# How update a field on the basis of condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have written store procedures as below,

```
INSERT INTO Slider
  (
    SliderID
   ,SliderTitle
   ,SliderDescription
   ,SliderImage
   ,BackgroundImage
   ,IsBackgroundEnabled
   ,PageName
   ,IsEnabled
   ,CreatedOn
  )
VALUES
  (
    NEWID()
   ,@SliderTitle
   ,@SliderDescription
   ,@SliderImage
   ,@BackgroundImage
   ,@IsBackgroundEnabled
   ,@PageName
   ,@IsEnabled
   ,GETDATE()
```

Now I want that if there are more than one record in `slider` table and currently adding record's `@IsBackgroundEnabled` property is true or 1 then all the other record's `@IsBackgroundEnabled` property should become false or 0.

**Note:** That currently added record's `@IsBackgroundEnabled` should be true.

Please help me!!

Comment: `UPDATE Slider SET IsBackgroundEnabled=0 WHERE CreatedOn=GETDATE()`

Comment: You may need a trigger for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your insert statement add this update statement:

```
IF @IsBackgroundEnabled = 1
UPDATE Slider 
SET IsBackgroundEnabled=0
```

Then add your insert statement

Answer (score 0):

For that, you may have to create trigger on Slider table like below,

```
CREATE TRIGGER SliderAfterInsert
ON [dbo].[Slider]
FOR  INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @latest AS INT 
    SET @latest = (
            SELECT TOP 1 IsBackgroundEnabled
            FROM   [Slider]
            WHERE  IsBackgroundEnabled = 1
            ORDER BY
                   CreatedOn
        )

    IF (@latest IS NOT NULL AND @latest<>0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Slider
        SET    IsBackgroundEnabled     = 0
        WHERE  CreatedOn               = GETDATE()
        PRINT 'SliderAfterInsert trigger fired.'
    END
GO
```

This will definitely help you.